# Are wild Pokemon predetermined to escape or stay?

Tags: pokemon-go

I travelled across the land, searching far and wide, and I was wondering:

Are wild Pokemon that you try to catch predetermined predetermined to run or get caught?

I recently caught a Blastoise, but when I tried catching it for someone else, it ran away. I used an ultra ball along with a razz berry, so it was out of my hands. We are both level 24, so level has nothing to do with it.

Does the game predetermine if it runs away when clicking the pokemon, or is it just random, depending on the player?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to [this guide](https://pokemongo.gamepress.gg/catch-mechanics) for an explanation on how the catching mechanics work in Pokemon Go.

While you and your friend(s) may have all done the exact same thing for the encounter, bonuses included, this does not guarantee that you will all catch it.

> Finally, the server generates a Random Number between 0% and 100.0%. If Final Capture Chance is greater than this random number, the Pokémon is caught. If Final Capture Rate is less than this random number, the Pokémon breaks out and possibly flees.

One of you may get a very high random number and the other very low. The one who received the lower number may capture it while the player who gets the higher number may not, at which point, the Pokemon may run away. At the end of the day, it's all luck (unless you've been soft banned).

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are many factors that affect a Pokemon's catch rate. In your example, you said that you were Level 24 trying to catch a Blastoise. You said that "we are both Level 24, so level has nothing to do with it." Pokemon actually get *more difficult* to capture as you level up, and Blastoise has one of the lowest catch rates in the game. So even with an Ultra Ball and a Razz Berry, it should not be surprising that it ran away. The same exact same thing with a Blastoise happened to me, I'm Level 20.
I would highly doubt that Pokemon are predetermined to run away when you tap on them because you can do things in battle to increase the catch rate, like Razz Berries. So I would think that it is just random, depending on the player level, rarity of the Pokemon, what type of Pokeball you are using, if you threw a Razz Berry at it, and even possibly if you might have been soft banned somewhere along the line.

Comment: I know that as level increases, pokemon get more difficult. Also, i caught the blastoise, they did not. I have not been soft banned, nor have they. Thank you for the answer.